# passing String to AsyncTask class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have the below class

```
public class Faculty extends Activity {

    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String NAME = "name";
    static String DESIGNATION = "designation";
    //static String POPULATION = "population";
    static String FAC_IMG = "fac_img";
    static String url;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstantState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstantState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.faculty_list);
        String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("Dpmt");
        if(data.equals("DOCScience")){
            url="Department%20Of%20Computer%20Science";
        }
        if(data.equals("DOIT")){
            url="Department%20Of%20Information%20%26%20Technology";
        }
        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute(url);

        //String url="http://192.168.170.89/bbau_faculty.php?dept="+Dept;
    }
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Faculty.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            //mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            String url1=params[0];
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            System.out.println(url1);
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://192.168.170.89/bbau_faculty.php?dept="+url1);
```

I am calling the DownloadJSON class
using the line

```
new DownloadJSON().execute(url);
```

In the DownloadJSON class the method

`doInBackground(String... params)`  I want to receive the url passed in `execute(url)`

```
String url1=params[0];
```

But `url1` is printing as null.

Comment: if(data.equals("DOIT")) return  true??? check this

Answer (score 1):

> But url1 is printing as null.

you are doing in the correct way. If you are receinving null as value it means, in your case, that

```
String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("Dpmt");
```

is not neither `DOCScience` nor `DOIT`, and `url` remains initialized with   with the default value (null for `String` declared as class member)

Comment: The case is matching DOCScience i.e. before the line
new DownloadJSON().execute(url);

Comment: check if you misspelled the word.  I would strongly suggest you to start using constants

Comment: Before the line

new DownloadJSON().execute(url);

if I print url I am getting 

Department%20Of%20Computer%20Science

it means one of the if statement is true
but still I am getting url1=null in the doinBackgroundTask

Comment: check if you misspelled the string, if it contains trailing and/or leading  spaces. Remember the equals is case sensitive too

Answer (score 0):

probably because data never equals DOCScience nor DOIT. Make sure you are getting and setting data with the correct key. Data might also be "" when setting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check `url` value before pass it to `AsyncTask` :

```
if(url !=null && url.trim().length()>0){
  new DownloadJSON().execute(url);
}
```

Also use `else-if` leader instead of multiple `if` in case of check data value which either `DOCScience`  or  `DOIT` :

```
if(data.equals("DOCScience")){
   url="Department%20Of%20Computer%20Science";
}else if(data.equals("DOIT")){
   url="Department%20Of%20Information%20%26%20Technology";
}else{
  // no match
}
```

Comment: Before the line new DownloadJSON().execute(url); if I print url I am getting Department%20Of%20Computer%20Science it means one of the if statement is true but still I am getting url1=null in the doinBackgroundTask